# wordpress wp_login action hook not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the code in my functions.php file:

```
add_action('wp_login', 'update_byc_meta', 10, 2);

function update_byc_meta ($user_login, $user) {
...
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for update_byc_meta() in /home/wp_4q8x83/backyardcures.com/wp-content/themes/backyard-cures/functions.php on line 154

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/wp_4q8x83/backyardcures.com/wp-content/themes/backyard-cures/functions.php:154) in /home/wp_4q8x83/backyardcures.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1173
```

The documentation says that the wp_login action hook provides 2 parameters and I am requesting them so I do not know why I am getting these errors...

Comment: You sure $user has a value ?

Comment: also look for do_action

Answer (score 0):

```
//Current User object
$cu = wp_get_current_user();
$login = $cu->login;

add_action( 'wp_login', 'update_byc_meta', 10, 2 );
function update_byc_meta( $login, $cu ) {
    //now we can changing meta value
    update_user_meta( $cu->ID, 'meta_field', 'meta_value' );
}
```

1. Setup current user object
2. Do somthing with meta via hook :)
   Propose short example above